# Relative spot in frame

Tags: iphone

I was asked to put some buttons on an image inside an object that is similar to scrollview.

There is no problem adding those buttons, but when I pinch the image to be small or bigger, the position of the button relative to the image is changing.

How can i make it stay?

Is there a way to use `myButton.frame = CGRectMake(30%,30%,x,y);` or something of that kind?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify `CGRectMake` parameters in percentages. I believe the solution to your problem lies in the `UIViewAutoResizingMask` property. Setting it to `UIViewAutoResizingNone` might do the trick.

```
myButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

In any case, the buttons shouldn't have resizingMask values set to any of the margins, because otherwise they'll keep that margin width constant.

**Edit:**
Another way can be to override the layoutSubviews method, which should be called when your imageView/scrollView resizes:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {   // Go through all subviews

        if (view == scrollView) {  // Find the scrollView object you want
           //then find the scrollView's frame size and reposition the button objects

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean i should set my scrollView.autoresizingmask to none?

Comment: No, not the scrollView, but its subviews (the buttons that should remain in the same position relative to the scrollView's size).

Comment: I tried both the button, scrollview and the self.autoresizingmask... Didn't work.

Comment: Then the solution has to be to override the `layoutSubviews` method. Let me edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Any luck with solving your problem?